# Error message when installing Ruby on Rails on Mojave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-mojave

When I try to install Ruby on Rails using the following commands...

```
sudo gem install rails
```

... I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

My OS is MacOS Mojave and I think this may be the reason why I am getting this message. What could I do to install Ruby on Rails? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `sudo` with `gem install`, because that will mess up your file system permissions, and you won't be able to run `rails`, or any other gem, commands without `sudo`, which can be harmful.

Use RVM or rbenv to manage Ruby versions. To install RVM, run (without sudo):

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then, follow any post install instructions and install the Ruby version you'd like:

```
rvm install 2.6.0
```

Then install `bundler` and `rails`:

```
gem install bundler
gem install rails
```

And you're done! Have a happy Ruby-life without file permission issues.

Comment: Great! Looked over 100 different answers and blogs and what have you. This one did the trick! rvm FTW!

Answer (score 1):

May for only install it, you can use `-n` option: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin rails`

But,i strongly recommends you to use a ruby manager, like RVM (https://rvm.io/rvm/install) supports MacOS, permits you to have multiple Ruby versions and keep all your gems organized by version.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dimitrius! I installed RVM with Ruby and Rails, but I am not sure how to use it in order to execute this: 

rails new MySite

Comment: Nice!! RVM its a really good manager. For your question, tell me the output if you execute one rvm command like `rvm list` or `rvm --version`

Comment: It's this:
* jruby-9.2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.3.7 [ x86_64 ]

Comment: Just install a `rvm version`, and after this, install `rails`